# C# How to end/kill a task properly

Tags: c#, task

I have this code, where I will need to use an API which gets data from the server, and while doing that I will display a loading indicator. I would like to provide an option for users to cancel the loading operation because it can take a long time to get data from the server.

My current code is similar to this:

```
var results = new DataTable();
var task = TplUtilities.StartNew(() =>            
{
    loadingIndicator.CancellationTokenSource.Token
        .Register(Thread.CurrentThread.Abort);
    results = api.getDataFromServer();
});
task.Wait();
```

My loading indicator has a cancel button, where if a user clicks on it, it will call loadingIndicator.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel().

This works, but I've read that aborting a thread isn't good. So, what's the proper way to end this task?

From what I researched, most examples have loops checking for `CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` or `CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested`, but I can't-do that in my task because it will be stuck at the API call.

Comment: You're right, aborting threads is bad. So you can't abort the call, simple as that. Just ignore it and it will go away by itself.

Comment: Enigmativity is right. If your API does not support cancellation "out of the box", then what you want is to *abandon* the task (that is, to cancel the asynchronous wait for the task's completion). [Here's a great guide on how to do it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/)